# Верстка блоков для мобильной версии

Tags: html, css, responsive

Есть 6 блоков которые стоят в столбик. Мне нужно, чтобы в мобильной версии они отображались по 2 блока на каждой строке. То есть всего 3 строки чтобы было.
Как это сделать, помогите. 
Вот код:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.picture-box {
  width: 70%;
  /* limit screen width - max width could have been used aswell */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* center content */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.ring {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Center ring div */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .ring {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .ring {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .ring {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .picture-box {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.thumb {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture-box">
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать псевдокласс nth-child, я думаю. + псевдоэлемент:after.
Что-то такое будет, видимо:

```
@media screen and (min-width: нужные разрешения экрана) {
        .ring: nth-child(2n) 
         after;
    }
```

Comment: не помогло. блоки все равно в ряд стоят(

Comment: Значит, нужен элемент break, который будет иметь ширину 100% на тех разрешениях, где нужно по 2 элемента в строку, и ширину 0 на тех разрешениях, где блоки в строку располагаются. Этот break вставляется там, где нужен разрыв. Т.е. между 2 и 3 блоком, между 4 и 5 ...   Хотя, предыдущий способ - точно рабочий. Просто Вам требуется его адаптировать к своему коду. Я просто пример привела.

Comment: @gremlina, окей. спасибо!